# Spring Security 3.2.5 and Active Directory in JBoss EAP 6.2 vs 6.3

Tags: jboss, spring-security, active-directory, jboss-eap-6

In my application, I am using Spring Security 3.2.5. I am trying to authenticate via ActiveDirectory using `org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`. I am testing a scenario that the password is wrong.

In JBoss EAP 6.2, I get `javax.naming.AuthenticationException`, this is handled in `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` in a correct way as it was expected by Spring Security. Below shows how this exception is handled in `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` from Spring Security 3.2.5:

```
try {
        return contextFactory.createContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        if ((e instanceof AuthenticationException) || (e instanceof OperationNotSupportedException)) {
            handleBindException(bindPrincipal, e);
            throw badCredentials(e);
        } else {
            throw LdapUtils.convertLdapException(e);
        }
    }
```

But when I test the same scenario with JBoss EAP 6.3, I get the `javax.naming.NamingException` instead so the logic goes to else statement. And in `LdapUtils.convertLdapException()` method, it returns the

```
return new org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException(ex);
```

and it ends up as error 500 since it is not an `AuthenticationException`.

Since Spring Security 3.2.5 code uses `instanceof`, and `AuthenticationException` is the root cause in the `NamingException` (you can see this by running `e.getCause()` while debugging), so the exception is not handled neither in `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` nor in `LdapUtils`.

I assume fixing this either in Spring Security or JBoss will take some time. I am desperately in need of a workaround solution. Since `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` is a final class, I can not easily make a custom class based on it. Any other idea apart from extending `AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider` and copy the whole thing from `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you let me know how did you resolve this?